# SharePoint Online File Explorer issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, explorer

We've been trying to move over staff shared drives into SharePoint Online. I created a document library for each department. We found a bulk upload tool which works fine and used it to upload documents to each library.

In SharePoint online I can see all files and folders fine (31000 list items). But the issue I am experiencing is the Explorer viewing of the mapped document library. The folders appear fine, but the files in some of the folders are not appearing. Do you know if this is related to the 5000 list item limit? Or something to do with the bulk upload tool? to tool I used was this one http://www.lieben.nu/liebensraum/o365uploader/

Any ideas/ solutions would be amazing.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you are experiencing the same but I had an issue displaying folders with 20.000+ items.

Turned out to be a limitation in the client machine's registry, namelly the `FileAttributesLimitInBytes` key under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WebClient\Parameters\`

Had to increase this value and then restart the **WebClient** service.

[image]

The place I got this from is no longer accessible (good thing I save local copies!) but it is stored in web archive [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150925100750/https://helpdesk.egnyte.com/hc/en-us/articles/201638444-Map-Drive-error-message-Windows-cannot-access-this-Disc-or-Windows-cannot-read-from-this-disk).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will try that now and see if it works :)

Comment: I kind of killed my mapped drive, I think I went crazy with the limit size. What was the value you inputted into your reg entry?

cheers

Comment: iirc default was 1000000 and new was 50000000

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than 5,000 items in the root of a given folder then the items will not show using WebDAV mapped drives due to the 5,000 item list view limit. You could move items out of the folder until you get below the limit then they should display.

You could try using an alternative network drive mapping tool like Zee Drive. Zee Drive should show the items in the folder even if the number of items in the folder exceeds the 5,000 item list view limit. Download a free trial of [Zee Drive, the network drive mapping tool for OneDrive for Business and SharePoint Online, here.](http://www.thinkscape.com/Map-Network-Drives-To-Office-365-OneDrive/)

Disclosure: Zee Drive is a commercial tool my company develops.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, does your tool use webdav as a protocol? We have brought into I am Cloud's version of drive mapper. They use webdav so have the same issue as Explorer. 
I am happy to move stuff out of the document library, but then it wouldn't be a like for like experience for the end user. Basicually staff want their whole department folder available as one document library on SharePoint Online, if that makes sense?

Comment: Hi Andy_G. Zee Drive uses a different implementation to the Microsoft WebDAV WebClient service so is not impacted by the 5,000 list view item threshold issue. You should find that all the items will display in the folder even when the folder has more than 5,000 items in its root.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the update. Out of interest do you do education discount?

Comment: Hi Andy_G. We offer a 50% discount to the corporate rate for qualifying education organisations (the non-profit rate).

Comment: Thanks for the update, I will pass this on.

Regards